# Laravel: Loop through and display multiple counts

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, loops

I want to be able to loop through every year and find the home wins/away wins for a given team in a given year. However, I feel like the way I am doing it now is criminally inefficient, but I am new to laravel and cannot figure out what exactly I need. Here is my controller:

```
  //Year 2005 First Rounds
  $roundoneyearonea= GameData::where('homeTeam', $teamdatas)->where('homeWin', '1')->where('stage', 'R16')->where('round', 'one')->where('year', '2005')->count();
  $roundoneyearoneb= GameData::where('awayteam', $teamdatas)->where('awayWin', '1')->where('stage', 'R16')->where('round', 'one')->where('year', '2005')->count();
  $roundoneyearone= $roundoneyearonea + $roundoneyearoneb;

  $roundoneyearonec= GameData::where('homeTeam', $teamdatas)->where('homeLoss', '1')->where('stage', 'R16')->where('round', 'one')->where('year', '2005')->count();
  $roundoneyearoned= GameData::where('awayteam', $teamdatas)->where('awayLoss', '1')->where('stage', 'R16')->where('round', 'one')->where('year', '2005')->count();
  $roundoneyearoneloss= $roundoneyearonec + $roundoneyearoned;

  //Year 2005 Second Rounds
  $roundtwoyearonea= GameData::where('homeTeam', $teamdatas)->where('homeWin', '1')->where('stage', 'R16')->where('round', 'two')->where('year', '2005')->count();
  $roundtwoyearoneb= GameData::where('awayteam', $teamdatas)->where('awayWin', '1')->where('stage', 'R16')->where('round', 'two')->where('year', '2005')->count();
  $roundtwoyearone= $roundtwoyearonea + $roundtwoyearoneb;

  $roundtwoyearonec= GameData::where('homeTeam', $teamdatas)->where('homeLoss', '1')->where('stage', 'R16')->where('round', 'two')->where('year', '2005')->count();
  $roundtwoyearoned= GameData::where('awayteam', $teamdatas)->where('awayLoss', '1')->where('stage', 'R16')->where('round', 'two')->where('year', '2005')->count();
  $roundtwoyearoneloss= $roundtwoyearonec + $roundtwoyearoned;
```

I am doing this for multiple rounds and multiple years and it is becoming ridiculous to say the least. Suggestions for looping?

Comment: Can you add your database schema?

Comment: id int(4) YES  
year int(4) YES  
game int(3) YES  
team varchar(14) YES  
opponent varchar(14) YES  
win varchar(1) YES  
loss varchar(10) YES  
tie varchar(1) YES  
stage varchar(9) YES  
round varchar(9) YES  
stageSeries varchar(1) YES  
seriesGame varchar(1) YES  
awayTeam varchar(14) YES  
homeTeam varchar(14) YES  
awayWin varchar(1) YES  
awayLoss varchar(1) YES  
awayTie varchar(1) YES  
homeWin varchar(1) YES  
homeLoss varchar(1) YES  
homeTie varchar(1) YES  
awayScore varchar(2) YES  
homeScore varchar(2) YES  
awayShots varchar(2) YES

Comment: I have yet to change the varchars to int where appropriate because I've been forced to import this data several times and I am doing it through imports as oppose to migrations. Could that cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that receives an interval of time and then use a whereIn statement

```
function createYearsArray()
{
    // Logic of the function

     return [
        2015,
        2016,
        2016,
    ]
 }

 $years = createYearsArray();

 $roundoneyearoned = GameData::where('awayteam', $teamdatas)
     ->where('awayLoss', '1')
     ->where('stage', 'R16')
     ->where('round', 'one')
     ->whereIn('year', $years)->count();
```

Comment: I am trying to get a count for each year individually to display in a table, I think I need a forloop of some kind. The code you provided seems to be adding the years together and providing that value. I do think that will be useful later on, so thanks!!